# Unable to execute tests in parallel using testng and maven surefire plugin

Tags: maven, testing, parallel-processing, maven-surefire-plugin

Need your help as i have been struggling with parallel execution using maven. i am trying to run Testng tests in parallel, maven V3.3.9, maven-surefire-plugin V2.18.1, with the below configurations.

```
<suiteXmlFiles>
  <suiteXmlFile>testng.xml</suiteXmlFile>
</suiteXmlFiles>
<parallel>classes</parallel>
<threadCount>10</threadCount>
```

and also tried `<suitethreadpoolsize>10</suitethreadpoolsize>`

But, tests aren't running in parallel. i have been searching extensively for two days but couldn't get it working. Tried all the suggestions available on google!! Need your inputs to find out where i might be wrong.